# Contradictory SFINAE on constructor using std::is_constructible

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Why is the following code behaving as commented?

```cpp
struct S
{
    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_constructible_v<S, T>>>
    S(T&&){}
};

int main() {
    S s1{1}; // OK
    int i = 1;
    S s2{i}; // OK
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<S, int>); // ERROR (any compiler)
}
```

I get that for the constructor to be enabled, the assertion must be false. But S still is constructed from int in the example above! What does the standard say and what does the compiler do?

I would assume that before enabling the template constructor, S in not constructible so `std::is_constructible<S, int>` instantiates to false. That enables the template constructor but also condemns std::is_constructible<S, int> to always test false.

---

I've also tested with my own (pseudo?) version of std::is_constructible:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename, typename T, typename... ARGS>
constexpr bool isConstructibleImpl = false;

template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
constexpr bool isConstructibleImpl<
    std::void_t<decltype(T(std::declval<ARGS>()...))>,
    T, ARGS...> =
    true;

template<typename T, typename... ARGS>
constexpr bool isConstructible_v = isConstructibleImpl<void, T, ARGS...>;

struct S
{
    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!isConstructible_v<S, T>>>
    S(T&&){}
};

int main() {
    S s1{1}; // OK
    int i = 1;
    S s2{i}; // OK
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<S, int>); // OK
}
```

I suppose that it is because now std::is_constructible is not sacrificed for SFINAE in the constructor. isConstructible is sacrificed instead.

That brings me to a second question: Is this last example a good way to perform SFINAE on a constructor without corrupting std::is_constructible?

---

**Rational:** I ended up trying that SFINAE pattern to tell the compiler not to use the template constructor if any of the other available constructors matches (especially the default ones), even imperfectly (e.g., a `const &` parameter should match a `&` argument and the template constructor should not be considered a better match).

Comment: Interestingly, the static assert isn't triggered if its `int` parameter is changed to `int &&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code example is undefined behaviour, because `S` is not a complete type within the declaration of itself. `std::is_constructible_v` however requires all involved types to be complete:

See these paragraphs from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible):

> T and all types in the parameter pack Args shall each be a complete
> type, (possibly cv-qualified) void, or an array of unknown bound.
> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If an instantiation of a template above depends, directly or
> indirectly, on an incomplete type, and that instantiation could yield
> a different result if that type were hypothetically completed, the
> behavior is undefined.

This makes sense because in order for the compiler to know if some type can be constructed it needs to know the full definition. In your first example, the code is kind of recursive: the compiler needs to find out if `S` can be constructed from `T` by checking the constructors of `S` which themselves depend on `is_constructible` etc.

Comment: When `is_constructible` is instantiated (in `main()`), `S` is already complete. It can't be instantiated when the declaration is first seen, because it depends on `T`.

Comment: Not sure why -1 that response. It sounds pretty clear to me and I feel slightly dumb now that I realized that I stopped reading cppreference a couple lines to early...

Comment: @Meatboy106 Because the answer is wrong, and I explained why in the previous comment?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could you please ellaborate? Does your comment refer to the first or second code snippet in the question? If you refer to the second, then what about the first and the instantiation of is_constructible in S::S? If you have a definitive answer, I would gladly accept it over that one.

Comment: @Meatboy106 I'm referring to the first snippet. I don't know the answer, unfortunately.